# discussion about the scenarios that the insertion function of an STL vector may not work

Tags: c++, vector, stl

it is strange that when I debugging a piece of code

```
a.insert(a.begin(), calculateSomeValue()); // a is of type std::vector<double>
```

this does not work because the value returned from the function calculateSomeValue is not inserted into a and the size of a does not increase.
but when I split it into two lines as the following, it works as I expect

```
 double value = calculateSomeValue();
 a.insert(a.begin(), value);
```

Do you happen to know what could be the possible reasons?

this is in windows

Comment: Where is your testcase?

Comment: I have to say this is not a seeking for debugging help because I have a way to get rid of this problem. I just want to discuss with people here possible causes of this problem to learn more.

Comment: I just think you guys did not think carefully before down voting people and once one people did so, all follows. The original title is clearly enough for the purpose of the dicusssion which includes all the key words like "STL vector" "Insert function" "does not work as expected".

Comment: @KKKii: You think wrong. You should put aside this "I am right, everyone else must be wrong" mindset and think about what _you_ did wrong. If you actually **read** the closure reason, everything you need to know is there. In short, "does not work as expected" is NOT ENOUGH, the code you showed us is NOT ENOUGH, to tell you what is going on here... and if you didn't want help debugging it but only "to discuss with people" then you should have phoned a friend or hired a mentor, because Stack Overflow is not a forum or discussion board.

Comment: I think you probably did not get my meaning of discussion or distorted it on purpose. I beleive many people asking discussion type of questions here. but Anyway.   It does not matter.

Comment: Right, and when they ask those questions, those questions get _closed_ because they are off-topic. It _does_ matter. Please do not accuse me of ignorance or malice just because you're upset your question got closed. As it happens, I know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume that a side effect of `calculateSomeValue()` is changing `a` which invalidates all iterators.

Since the order of evaluation of arguments in `a.insert(a.begin(), calculateSomeValue());` is unspecified it could be that `a.begin()` is evaluated before `calculateSomeValue()` invalidates all iterators to `a`. Which is undefined behaviour.